# What are some options for an offline chatbot on Android?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have already created an online chatbot for my Android app using Dialogflow (formerly api.ai). It allows users to add a new item to their inventory. I now need to create an offline version of this chatbot. However, Dialogflow does not allow you to download the agent to work offline.

I have looked into several options, including RiveScript and ALICE (Pandorabots). These seem to be a bit too low-level for my purposes and require quite a bit of customization. I was wondering if there are any options similar to Dialogflow that can be used offline.

Comment: did you finally find any offline bot for Android? Thank you

Comment: This is something I'm looking for as well. App Actions and slices are already reaching into Assistant territory a bit, but there's nothing similar to DialogFlow yet as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 2):

EasyNLU project might interest you: https://github.com/kolloldas/EasyNLU

> EasyNLU is a Natural Language Understanding (NLU) library written in Java for mobile apps. Being grammar based, it is a good fit for domains that are narrow but require tight control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rasa](https://rasa.com/). There is an option to [migrate from DialogFlow to Rasa](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/migrate-from/google-dialogflow-to-rasa/). You can refer to [this blog](https://blog.rasa.com/how-to-migrate-your-existing-google-dialogflow-assistant-to-rasa/) for migration.

Comment: The OP said offline and on Android ; I don't think Rasa can do this